# Force javac to run processors

Tags: annotations, javac, annotation-processing

AFAIK when some errors were reported from within one processor, other will not be run.
Is there any way to force processing independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html), only uncaught errors or exceptions stop further processing:

> If a processor throws an uncaught exception, the tool may cease other active annotation processors. [...] Since annotation processors are run in a cooperative environment, a processor should throw an uncaught exception only in situations where no error recovery or reporting is feasible.

If a processor reports an error, the [`errorRaised()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/RoundEnvironment.html#errorRaised%28%29) method should return true in the next round but not stop processing:

> Printing a message with an error kind will raise an error.

> If a processor raises an error, the current round will run to completion and the subsequent round will indicate an error was raised.

It says "the tool *may* cease other active annotation processors" (emphasis added). So if you need to keep going on even in case of uncaught exceptions, it should be possible with the right processing tool. I don't know if there are any tools that support this though. At least the processing tool should be the direction to look for if you need this feature.